# How to find out the format of bytes? NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

What I'm trying to make: Receive data from microphone (IWaveIn) => lower the amplitude of the sound(lower the volume)(problem) => play it to the speakers(IWaveProvider)

The problem is: whenever I try to multiply sample by x!=1.0f gives me very noisy feedback.
I think it could be a format of bytes but I do not know how to check it. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Count = 17640; Offset =0;

```
public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int read = bufferedWaveProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        /*
                waveIn.WaveFormat.Channels; //2
                waveIn.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;//4
                waveIn.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;//16
                waveIn.WaveFormat.SampleRate;//44100
         */

        for (int i = 0; i < read / 4; i++)
        {
            int firstByte = i * 4;
            float sample = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, firstByte);
            sample = sample * 1.0f;

            byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(sample);
            buffer[firstByte + 0] = bytes[0];
            buffer[firstByte + 1] = bytes[1];
            buffer[firstByte + 2] = bytes[2];
            buffer[firstByte + 3] = bytes[3];
        }

        return read;
    }
    private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving audio in the format specified in `WaveIn.WaveFormat`. Your comment shows 16 bits per sample, which means you are receiving the audio as signed 16 bit samples. So you could use `BitConverter.ToInt16`

But there are easier ways of accomplishing this. If you call `ToSampleProvider()` on your `BufferedWaveProvider` then you can pass that into a `VolumeSampleProvider` which will let you adjust the volume directly without needing to unpack samples yourself.

Comment: I know there is the way to use ToSampleProvider() but I'm planning adding some other effects(not just volume). Thanks for the answer this was the case. What if the waveformat.bitspersample != 16, lets say 32bits/sample can be converted to int32 or float? Is there any table that shows which waveformat can be converted to which data type? And again thanks for help in this specific case.

Comment: ToSampleProvider handles the most commonly encountered formats - 16bit, 24 bit, 32bit int, 32 bit float